# XCopy one directory to different destination

Tags: batch-file

Just want to ask, can you copy one entire directory to multiple destination?

```
Example 

Source:        "c:\MyProject\Sample\*.*"
Destination:   "\\Computer1\Sample\"
               "\\Computer2\Sample\"
               "\\Computer3\Sample\"
               "\\Computer4\Sample\"
```

I used this syntax to copy the entire directory

Example

Xcopy /E /Y "c:\MyProject\Sample*.*" "\Computer1\Sample\"

Now, Is there a way to loop through the following destination..? Do you have any suggestion on i can accomplish this scenario..?

Hope to hear from you soon..

Thanks,

Link

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
for %%D in (
  "\\Computer1\Sample\"
  "\\Computer2\Sample\"
  "\\Computer3\Sample\"
  "\\Computer4\Sample\"
) do Xcopy /E /Y "c:\MyProject\Sample*.*" "%%D"
```

The above assumes you are using a batch file. If run from the command line, then use `%D` instead of `%%D`. Also, the entire command can be put on one line, with spaces as path delimiters.

Comment: Hi dbenhan, Just a quick question, is there away to validate the file before copying.. my sample contains several files.. now, i want to copy all file except for one.. is this possible.? hope to hear from you soon.. thanks..

Comment: @link - Sorry, I overlooked your comment until now. Type `HELP XCOPY` or `XCOPY /?` from the command line and you will see all the options available. You can try the `/EXCLUDE:` option. But sometimes it is not specific enough to meet your needs. You could try the `ROBOCOPY` command instead (`HELP ROBOCOPY` or `ROBOCOPY /?`). It is very powerful and precise.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a batch file that has multiple xcopies to achieve this

```
Xcopy /E /Y "c:\MyProject\Sample*.*" "\Computer1\Sample\"
Xcopy /E /Y "c:\MyProject\Sample*.*" "\Computer2\Sample\"
Xcopy /E /Y "c:\MyProject\Sample*.*" "\Computer3\Sample\"
Xcopy /E /Y "c:\MyProject\Sample*.*" "\Computer4\Sample\"
```

Comment: I actually thought of this, but i want it to be more simple, like adding a loop function for a batch file.. is that possible..?

Comment: you can have a loop approach as below for %%D in (
  "\\Computer1\*"
) do Xcopy /E /Y "c:\MyProject\Sample*.*" "%%D"

Comment: Hi  Vijay EK, Just a quick question, is there away to validate the file before copying.. my sample contains several files.. now, i want to copy all file except for one.. is this possible.? hope to hear from you soon.. thanks

Comment: I dont think you can validate the file using xcopy.  You may have to write some kind of scripting for that like vbscript or autoit